# AutoSuggestBox sugestion lists not closing during scroll in UWP

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

`AutoSuggestBox` suggestion list aren't closing  during scroll which causes weird UI issue. The issue will look like the one below, which i have taken from the default **XAML Controls Gallery** application.

[image]

A simple `AutoSuggestBox` i have tested

```
<AutoSuggestBox TextChanged="AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged" Width="300" />
```

Is there a better way to fix this other than using **`ScrollViewer.ViewChanged`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AutoSuggestBox sugestion lists not closing during scroll in UWP

We could not set the Popup `IsLightDismissEnabled` as true, it will cause the popup could not display the content stable. I check your screenshot, you could set `ShouldConstrainToRootBounds` for `Pupup` control to avoid the list go though the bounds.

```
private void AutoSuggestBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var popup = MyFindGridViewChildByName(sender as AutoSuggestBox, "SuggestionsPopup") as Popup;
    popup.ShouldConstrainToRootBounds = true;
}
public static DependencyObject MyFindGridViewChildByName(DependencyObject parant, string ControlName)
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parant);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var MyChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parant, i);
        if (MyChild is FrameworkElement && ((FrameworkElement)MyChild).Name == ControlName)
            return MyChild;

        var FindResult = MyFindGridViewChildByName(MyChild, ControlName);
        if (FindResult != null)
            return FindResult;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I tested your code. `ShouldConstrainToRootBounds` it helps to constraint the popup only within the Window but not within the header. is there a way to restrict within the header as the bound?

Comment: The popup will follow the the `AutoSuggestBox`, if the  `AutoSuggestBox` scroll out the display air and the popup will scroll out to, it could not fix below the header. And it is by-design.