# AutoSuggestBox suggestions appear outside of app window

Tags: uwp-xaml

I'm experiencing some very odd behavior with an AutoSuggestBox in a UWP application.

In particular, if the AutoSuggestBox appears in a ScrollViewer and is not currently visible on the screen, its suggestions open anyway and the suggestion list appears outside of the main window of my application (at approximately the same place where they might appear if the application window were larger).

There are at least two problems here. One is that I don't know why the suggestions are appearing at all, since I didn't click on the control or do anything in code that should cause it to open.

Even weirder is the fact that the list of suggestions appears outside of the application's window. I didn't think it was possible for a xaml control to exceed the boundaries of its container, let alone those of the application.

Frank

Answer (score 0):

> AutoSuggestBox suggestions appear outside of app window

Please check this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58709285/7254781),in latest version We add [`ShouldConstrainToRootBounds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup.shouldconstraintorootbounds) for Pupup control, you could set it as true to  avoid the list go though the bounds.

```
private void AutoSuggestBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var popup = MyFindGridViewChildByName(sender as AutoSuggestBox, "SuggestionsPopup") as Popup;
    popup.ShouldConstrainToRootBounds = true;
}
public static DependencyObject MyFindGridViewChildByName(DependencyObject parant, string ControlName)
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parant);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var MyChild = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parant, i);
        if (MyChild is FrameworkElement && ((FrameworkElement)MyChild).Name == ControlName)
            return MyChild;

        var FindResult = MyFindGridViewChildByName(MyChild, ControlName);
        if (FindResult != null)
            return FindResult;
    }

    return null;
}
```